# Prove that $|\mathcal{F}|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $\mathcal{F} = \Big\{ \mathcal{I}_{a,b}\times\{x\} :  a,b,x\in\mathbb{R}\Big\}$, where $\mathcal{I}_{a,b}:=\{\zeta\in\mathbb{R} :  a < \zeta <b\}$. Im trying to prove that $|\mathcal{F}|=|\mathbb{R}|$ (that can be denoted by $\mathfrak{c}).$

Please, can someone help with a clue our something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f: \mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}_{a,b} \times \{x\} \mapsto (a,b,x).
\end{align*}
It should be easy to show that this is injective, so that $|\mathcal{F}|\leq |\mathbb{R}^3|$.  Also notice that for any fixed $a < b$, $\mathcal{A} = \{\mathcal{I}_{a,b} \times \{x\} \,:\, x\in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$. 
 But there is a bijection from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ via
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}_{a,b} \times \{x\} \mapsto x
\end{align*}
so $|\mathbb{R}| \leq |\mathcal{F}| \leq |\mathbb{R}^3|$.
Now it comes down to arguing that $|\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}^3|$.

Comment: You don’t really map a set to an element. It’s either $\text{set}\to\text{set}$ or $\text{element}\mapsto\text{element}$.

Comment: I don't see any problem with what I have.  I'm simply mapping elements of $\mathcal{A}$ (whose elements are sets) to elements of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand

Answer (score 1):

You might try to show that $|\mathcal{F}| = |\mathbb{R}^3|$. Then you need only show that $|\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}^3|$ (or, more generally, $\mathbb{R}^n$).